# Rails - Why am I getting 'You are being redirected' in integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, integration-testing

When writing integration tests for a Rails 5 application I encountered the infamous 'You are being redirected' page for no apparent to me reasons. There are two highly similar tests:

```
test "GETtting correct activation link on an already activated user gives error message and redirects to root url" do
    # GIVEN a non-yet-registered email address
    email_address = "tester@testing.net"
    # GIVEN the sign-up page has been displayd
    get signup_path
    # GIVEN new user is created
    post signup_path, params: { user: { email: email_address, email_confirmation: email_address, password: "testpassword", password_confirmation: "testpassword" } }
    # GIVEN the URI from activation email
    activation_uri = URI.extract(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.text_part.body.encoded)[0]
    # GIVEN the URI's been used and the user is already activated
    get activation_uri
    # WHEN reading back the newly activated user
    activated_user = User.find_by_email(email_address)
    # EXPECT the user to be activated
    assert activated_user.activated?
    # WHEN using the activation link on an already activated user
    get activation_uri
    # EXPECT redirection to root path
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    # EXPECT flash message
    assert_not flash.empty?
    # EXPECT rendered page to contain activation error information
    assert_select 'div#flash div h5', text: I18n.translate('users.activate.error')
end
```

which finishes correctly, and the next one:

```
test "GETtting incorrect activation hash on a non-activated user gives error message and redirects to root url" do
    # GIVEN a non-yet-registered email address
    email_address = "tester@testing.net"
    # GIVEN the sign-up page has been displayd
    get signup_path
    # GIVEN new user is created
    post signup_path, params: { user: { email: email_address, email_confirmation: email_address, password: "testpassword", password_confirmation: "testpassword" } }
    # WEHN GETting the activation URI with invalid activation hash
    activation_uri = "http://localhost:3000/account_activations/waTbfcCoZoPTBEIcewsl8Q/edit?email=#{ERB::Util.url_encode(email_address)}"
    get activation_uri
    # EXPECT redirection to root path
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    # EXPECT flash message
    assert_not flash.empty?
    # EXPECT rendered page to contain activation error information ('You are being redirected' rendered here)
    assert_select 'div#flash div h5', text: I18n.translate('users.activate.error')
end
```

which fails miserably on the last assert because 'You are being redirected' is being rendered instead of the page I am expecting to be rendered. In both cases I use `follow_redirect!` and the first one works, while the second one doesn't. The static URL in the second test is correct. It only uses a valid but non-associated hash instead of the expected one. In the controller there is simple

```
flash[:error] = "#{t'users.activate.error'}"
redirect_to root_url
```

in both cases (the same method). I receive proper `302` response code and proper redirection URL. When doing the same tests manually in the browser, correct page is rendered. When running the tests I get 'You are being…' in the second test.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's happen due to authorisation problem, you are calling a method with the data that does'not have access to that method, and it redirect it to somewhere. I have faced similar problem when i was trying to redirect with status code 401(unauthorised)

Comment: Hm - well, I don't change the code. I get the correct 302. I also get the correct redirection URL. Yet the 'you are being' page is rendered rather than the redirection taking place. When I use the same GET urls in the browser things work as expected. The only difference between the two calls is the activation hash. I'll try to have a closer look at the flow with the improper hash and see if it doesn't divert somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try, `puts response.body` in there to see whats going on?

There's a blurp in hartl's rails tutorial that helped me during a similar situation ... I applied his trick in a similar devise situation, honestly I'm not completely sure without poking around your code that the redirect is from a bad URI or not - but thought I'd leave this here for anyone else with issues.  I stumbled your post when looking for some answers to devise redirects myself (though mine are probably related to ID not found issues).

```
When I originally wrote this chapter, I couldn’t recall offhand how to escape URLs in Rails, and figuring it out was pure technical sophistication (Box 1.1). What I did was Google “ruby rails escape url”, which led me to find two main possibilities, URI.encode(str) and CGI.escape(str). Trying them both revealed that the latter works. (It turns out there’s a third possibility: the ERB::Util library supplies a url_encode method that has the same effect.)
```